# Extract bash command suggestions from a node script

Tags: node.js, bash, input, autocomplete, tabs

Is there a way to fetch the output that bash input autocompletion will display when pressing "TAB" + "TAB" in a terminal?

I want to write a node script which will display these suggestions for a specific string. It might be a part of a command, a command with already provided options etc.

Comment: I believe the way bash autocompletes is by detecting if the user is trying to enter a command or a file path. If bash detects the user is trying to enter a file, I assume it uses [`readdir()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) (a C function) to get the files in the directory. So you would need to do something of a similar fashion in JavaScript/node.